# grunt watch/livereload fails on CSS preprocessing

Tags: javascript, css, gruntjs, watch, livereload

I've got an angular SPA application. Its CSS is generated from [stylus](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/). I am also using [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) for building/development automation.

### grunt-contrib-watch: CSS reload

**The thing I'm having trouble (in fact, I'm stuck with) is configuring grunt to reload *CSS* inside the browser (without browser refreshing entire page), when the developer changes *source* files**.. These are *stylus*, but I believe it has nothing to do here, it could be *sass/compass/less* or whatever and the problem would be the same.

Below is the solution I've got now:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  cfg: {
    service: {
      livereload: {
        port: 3955
      }
    },
    paths: {
      root: __dirname,
      serve: '<%= cfg.paths.root %>/.tmp/serve',
    },
  },
  stylus: {
    options: {
      paths: ['.tmp'],
      import: ['nib']
    },
    compile: {
      files: {
        '<%= cfg.paths.serve %>/app.css': 'app/styles/index.styl' // stylus main file
      }
    }
  },
  watch: {
    stylus: {
      files: ['app/**/*.styl'],
      tasks: ['stylus'],
      options: {
        spawn: false,
        livereload: false,
//      interrupt: true,
//      livereload: '<%= cfg.service.livereload.port %>'
      }
    },
    appStyles: {
      options: {
        livereload: '<%= cfg.service.livereload.port %>'
      },
      files: [
        '<%= cfg.paths.serve %>/app.css'
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

The project is really big, but I've tried to remove the irrelevant parts. Anyway, there is `app/styles` directory with `.styl` stylus files in it. When there is any change on stylus files, `watch:stylus` is fired to preprocess stylus into CSS: `.tmp/serve/app.css` file is created.

Then, there is another watcher, `watch:appStyles`, which listens on changes on `.tmp/serve/app.css`, and when they are noticed, the browser reload the CSS only.

The problem is that it works, more or less, 1 out of 10 times. This seems like a race condition - but I can't find where the race is.

The watch task starts with:

```
Running "watch" task
Waiting...
```

When I change `app/styles/*.styl` files, sometimes I get:

```
>> File "app\styles\_colors.styl" changed.

Running "stylus:compile" (stylus) task
File C:\development\mp-frontend\.tmp\serve\app.css created.

Running "watch" task
Completed in 0.858s at Wed Apr 15 2015 18:39:40 GMT+0200 (Rom, sommertid) - Waiting...
>> File ".tmp\serve\app.css" changed.

Running "watch" task
Completed in 0.018s at Wed Apr 15 2015 18:39:40 GMT+0200 (Rom, sommertid) - Waiting...
```

what means that the watcher `watch:stylus` has fired `stylus:compile` which created the file `.tmp\serve\app.css`. The `.tmp\serve\app.css` file change has been notified by `watch:appStyles` and the browser has reloaded its CSS, everything works fine. But this is very rarely.

Most of the times, I get:

```
>> File "app\styles\_colors.styl" changed.

Running "stylus:compile" (stylus) task
File C:\development\mp-frontend\.tmp\serve\app.css created.

Running "watch" task
Completed in 1.017s at Wed Apr 15 2015 18:38:51 GMT+0200 (Rom, sommertid) - Waiting...
```

what means that the watcher `watch:stylus` has fired `stylus:compile` which created the file `.tmp\serve\app.css`. And it stops here! `.tmp/serve/app.css` change is **not** noticed and the second watcher is not fired.

When I don't modify stylus (source files) and just edit manually the produced `.tmp/serve/app.css` just to see what happens - the browser CSS reload works fine.

Hence, I think there is some kind of race condition and I don't know where.

I've been trying manipulating the watch/livereload grunt options (see commented lines) but none combination worked for me.

I've been also trying to follow https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch#live-reload-with-preprocessors but can't see the error in my solution...